# Enable and disable auto rotate programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9

I would like to programmatically disable or enable the auto rotate function using a button using Swift. I was thinking that it might be able to somehow be done using the `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` function, but I am very confused after looking through the literature about how this is done. Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: You can only "disable" the auto rotation for your app, not the entire OS! Are you aware of that and only asking how to disable the rotation for your app?

Comment: Yes, I would like to prevent the rotation of my app when I press a button. Then I would like to trigger the app to retain rotating when I press other button. It doesn't seem as straightforward to me as I would have thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an action for the button that sets a boolean flag somewhere in your code and return the value of that flag in the `shouldAutorotate` method of the view controller. If you need that for all view controllers you could create a common base view controller (inheritance).

Example of button action:

```
@IBAction func toggleRotation(sender: Button) {
    // A made up AppConfig class with class method for setting and retrieving 
    // rotation flag.
    AppConfig.allowRotation(!AppConfig.allowRotation)
}
```

Example of shouldAutorotate:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return AppConfig.allowRotation()
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate

Comment: This was a tremendous help to me Snusmumrikken. I am going to try this out, when the bool is changed by the press of a button: override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return boolTrueOrFalse
}

Comment: It is enough that the `shouldAutorotate` method returns the boolean value that reflects your wish of either allowing rotation or not. The iOS framework will call the `shouldAutorotate`  method when it needs to by itself and then it will get the boolean value.